# Ace editor incorrectly sets its height until width is updated (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In an Angular.js application, I am embedding the [Ace editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) into a div which I size programmatically by setting its `width`.

This works in Internet Explorer and Firefox, but shows a strange behavior in Chrome: After initializing, in most cases, the editor is too tall:

[image: screenshot from Chrome developer tools]

The `ace-text-editor`-`div` has height `326px`, although the surrounding `div`s only have height `262px`. Even calling `editor.resize(true)` does not fix this. However, as soon as the *width* of the `editorWindow`-`div` is changed (e.g. by setting it directly in the developer tools), the height automatically corrects, and auto-updates correctly for the rest of this session.

On the page, some elements are loaded lazily, need vertical space, and cause the `editorWindow`-`div` to shrink - so it looks like the `ace-text-editor`-`div` fails to update to that. But it baffles me that this only is an issue in Chrome, and only until the first the the width changes after Ace loaded.

If I omit all calls to Ace-APIs, and fill the same `div` used by Ace with a `<textarea ng-model="data.core" ng-disabled="readOnly" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; resize: none">`, sizing works correctly.

What could cause this behavior? I'm certain that manually changing the width does not trigger any events in my code, since I only watch `resize`-events for the whole window.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to repair. You have to set parent's height explicitly. Initial sources:

HTML:

```
<div class="ace-holder">
    <div class="ace-editor">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ace-editor {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
ace.edit("ace-editor");
```

**Ace** overrides styles of container it's binded (`ace-editor` in this example) and size is lost. To repair set parent's size explicit too:

```
.ace-holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It works if you did't forget to setup **Ace** correctly:

```
editor.setAutoScrollEditorIntoView(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm no longer using Ace in this project, but it may help someone else `:-)`

Comment: @fefrei is it possible to know which editor you use now?

Comment: I'm using [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) now - recommended!

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but a workaround:

With JavaScript, on each `resize` event, get the `height` and `width` of the `editorWindow`, and directly set it to the `ace-text-editor`-`div`, then let Ace `resize()`.

Like so:

```
var editorDiv = element.find('.ace-text-editor');
var editor = ace.edit(editorDiv.get(0));
scope.$on('updateSizes', function () { // fired in my app when things resize
    editorDiv.width(element.parent().width());
    editorDiv.height(element.parent().height());
    editor.resize();
});
```

I'm still looking for an explanation or *real* solution.

Comment: The way you set width/height didn't work for me. This did:
    $(editor.container).width(...);
    //editor.resize() is not needed.